# Can I iterate through an array of arrays and compare it to an array of integers

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`.  I also have an array of integers `[3,4,5,6,8]`.

Is it possible for me to check if my integers match a complete array in the array of arrays?

So I have `4,5,6` in the int array, and it matches the middle array `[4,5,6]`.

Comment: You are on right track, you can iterate array of array and compare it with integers array and you are done. Give it a shot and add your solution here.

Comment: My effort has pretty much consisted of a whole lot of google/stack overflow searching.
I dont even know if it is possible, but if I had to guess I would say that I would iterate through the array of arrays and somehow compare that to the integers in the array of integers.

Comment: Is the order of elements important, i.e. would `[3,8,5]` also match?

Comment: Please add an example to your question. The answers below are making different assumptions about what you expect: ``true`` or ``false`` vs ``[4,5,6]`` or even ``[3,4,5,6,8]``

Comment: Does  `[4,1,5,6]` match? If one element of the first array were `[4,4,5,6]` would `[4,5,6]` match?

Comment: I was not 100% sure what I needed to to return when I asked the question yesterday.
I used the answer Ursus provided, which returned true, and that worked for what I needed it to do.
It did not matter what order the integers were in the array of integers.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
integers = [3,4,5,6,8]

a.any? { |sub_array| sub_array.all? { |item| integers.include? item } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
array_1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
array_2 = [3,4,5,6,8]

array_1.any? { |e| (e - array_2).empty? }
# => true
```

Comment: You answer assumes ``array_1`` items are the same size as ``array_2``

Comment: No, in the answer you can see that the `array_1` items and `array_2`  are of different size. Can u show an example that fails?

Comment: You're right. I missed the order of subtraction. OTOH the empty case (``array_1 = [[1,2,3],[],[7,8,9]]``) will report a false positive.

Comment: If you remove the map, ``array_1.any?{ |e| (e - array_2).empty? }`` you will get the same result and you will iterate the array one less time.

Comment: OP didn't mention about empty array elements. So I guess it's not an issue. I have removed `map` as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
array1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
array2 = [4,5,6]

result = array1.map{|inner_array| inner_array - array2}
# => [[1, 2, 3], [], [7, 8, 9]]

result.any?{|inner_array| inner_array.empty?}
# => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you expect a `true` or `false` and order doesn't matter, the following works:

```
require 'set'

a1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
a2 = [3,4,5,6,8]

a1.any? { |item| item.to_set.subset? a2.to_set } #=> true
```

Assuming you want the `index` into `a1` or `nil`

```
a1.index { |item| item.to_set.subset? a2.to_set }
```

Assuming you want the subset itself or `nil`

```
index = a1.index { |item| item.to_set.subset? a2.to_set }
index && a1[index]
```